# method="GET" gives empty $_GET, method="POST" gives non empty $_GET. Why? (PHP 5.6.6)

Tags: php, forms, post, get, submit

*test.php*:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
```

*submit_get.php*:

```html
<form action="test.php?param=some" method="GET">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

*submit_post.php*:

```html
<form action="test.php?param=some" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Submitting submit_get.php gives something like this:

> **array** *(size=0)*
>  empty
>  **array**
>   *(size=0)*
>  empty

Submitting submit_post.php outputs something like this:

> **array** *(size=1)*
>  'param' => string 'some'
>   *(length=4)*
>  **array** *(size=0)*
>  empty

So, I do not quite get how are POST and GET methods are connected with $_POST and $_GET PHP variables and why a submitted form with method="POST" outputs empty $_POST and non-empty $_GET?

Comment: what happens when you change `test.php/?param=some` to `test.php?param=some` ? (remove the / after test.php)

Comment: besides that ^ - remember to use `!empty()` and/or `isset()`

Comment: *"what happens when you change test.php/?param=some to test.php?param=some ?"* - Magic - @Maximus2012

Comment: Are you sure you have empty result from from GET?not from POST?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this, but doing `test.php/` <= the slash is probably instructing the server to go back to the root of the server. You're probably getting an unshown notice of a 404 but you're masking it in not using error reporting or that it isn't set by default on your server.

Comment: Yep, slashes don't have to be there. Removed "/", but don't see any changes as a result... @Maximus2012

Comment: I get the result showed @sergio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A form sent via GET needs to have all values defined inside the form. The browser will then create the query string from these values (according to form evaluation rules, things like "successful controls" etc). Creating this query string means that any existing query string in the action URL gets replaced. If you need to have a fixed value inside the query string, use hidden form fields.

When using POST forms, all data from the form goes into the body of the request instead of replacing the query string. So there is no replacement taking place, and the query string in the action URL survives.

You probably are taking the superglobal variable names POST and GET too literal. `$_GET` is the parsed query string, it's independent of the HTTP method, i.e. it will always be present, even with POST, PUT and DELETE requests. `$_POST` is the parsed HTTP body when conforming to some constraints (the content-type header has to specify either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`, and I think the method really has to be "POST" - "PUT" won't work that way, and "DELETE" must not have a HTTP body). Note that when NOT conforming to the constraints, even if you'd use the POST method, you won't get any data inside `$_POST`.

Comment: This is very helpful explanation. Vote it up when enough reputation,

Answer (score 0):

Don't put any URL parameters in your form action. Make a hidden input and populate it instead. Having the parameters as a query string in the URL when you call POST passes that parameter as GET, not POST. This is why we make the hidden input, so that it will be passed as POST and not GET.

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="param" value="some">
</form>
```

Comment: It is an advice, but not the answer why such result

Comment: they can do what they're doing now, just modified slightly. Look at their code again very carefully, including comments left under their question.

Comment: Modified my answer slightly to include a brief explanation on reasoning why the answer is what it is. While removing the `/` is an option, the issue with the query string still remains.